# Why does the default Object.toString() return a hex representation of the hashCode?

Tags: java, hash, tostring, hashcode

I'm curious why `Object.toString()` returns this:

```
return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
```

as opposed to this:

```
return getClass().getName() + "@" + hashCode();
```

What benefits does displaying the hash code as a hex rather than a decimal buy you?

Comment: Closely related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`Object.hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) used to be computed [based on a memory location where the object is located](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10107092/1968). Memory locations are almost universally displayed as hexadecimal.

The default return value of `toString` isn’t so much interested in the hash code but rather in a way to uniquely identify the object for the purpose of debugging, and the hash code serve well for the purpose of identification (in fact, the combination of class name + memory address is truly unique; and while a hash code isn’t guaranteed to be unique, it often comes close).

Comment: strictly speaking `Object.hashCode()`, it returns a number that *for some JVMs* is the based on the location of the object *at the time when the method is first called*.  The GC may relocate the object, but the `hashCode` must remain the same.

Comment: Are there in fact **any** JVMs for which it returns the memory location?

Comment: The statement that "`Object.hashCode` by default return a memory adress" is wrong for all Sun/Oracle JVMs released in the past decade, c.f. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105420/java-object-hashcode-address-or-random/16105878#16105878. Did you have some other JVM implementations in mind or did you mean to say that hashCode **used to** return a memory location?

Comment: @meriton This is good to know. My information was based [on the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()), which implies (apparently incorrectly) that a memory address is usually used. I should have clarified that the memory address is *used* in the computation of the hash code, rather than *being* the hash code. At any rate, I’ll update the answer.

Comment: @Raedwald Thanks for bringing this to my attention; see my previous reply and the updated answer.

Comment: The documentation finally got fixed, first [they removed the “typically”](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) saying that it “*may or may not be implemented as some function of an object's memory address at some point in time*”, then, [they removed the mentioning of addresses completely](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()), which was a good decision, imho.

Answer (score 13):

#### The Short Answer:

Hash Codes are usually displayed in hexadecimal because this way it is easier for us to retain them in our short-term memory, since hexadecimal numbers are shorter and have a larger character variety than the same numbers expressed in decimal.

Also, (as supercat states in a comment,) hexadecimal representation tends to prevent folks from trying to assign some meaning to the numbers, because they don't have any. (To use supercat's example,  `Fnord@194` is absolutely not the 194th `Fnord`; it is just `Fnord` with some unique number next to it.)

#### The Long Answer:

Decimal is convenient for two things:

- Doing arithmetic
- Estimating magnitude

However, these operations are inapplicable to hashcodes. You are certainly not going to be adding hashcodes together in your head, nor would you ever care how big a hashcode is compared to another hashcode.

What you are likely to be doing with hashcodes is the one and only thing that they were intended for: to tell whether two hash codes possibly refer to the same object, or definitely refer to different objects.

In other words, you will be using them as unique identifiers or *mnemonics* for objects. Thus, the fact that a hashcode is a number is in fact entirely irrelevant; you might as well think of it as a hash string.

Well, it just so happens that our brains find it a lot easier to retain in short-term memory (for the purpose of comparison) short strings consisting of 16 different characters, than longer strings consisting of only 10 different characters.

To further illustrate the analogy by taking it to absurdity, imagine if hash  codes were represented in binary, where each number is far longer than in decimal, and has a much smaller character variety. If you saw the hash code 010001011011100010100100101011 now, and again 10 seconds later, would you stand the slightest chance of being able to tell that you are looking at the same hash code?  (I can't, even if I am looking at the two numbers simultaneously. I have to compare them digit by digit.)

On the opposite end lies the tetrasexagesimal numbering system, which means base 64. Numbers in this system consist of:

- the digits 0-9, plus:
- the uppercase letters A-Z, plus:
- the lowercase letters a-z, plus:
- a couple of symbols like '+' and '/' to reach 64.

Tetrasexagesimal obviously has a much greater character variety than lower-base systems, and it should come as no surprise that numbers expressed in it are admirably terse. (I am not sure why the JVM is not using this system for hashcodes; perhaps some prude feared that chance might lead to certain inconvenient four-letter words being formed?)

So, on a hypothetical JVM with 32-bit object hash codes, the hash code of your "Foo" object could look like any of the following:

```
Binary:           com.acme.Foo@11000001110101010110101100100011
Decimal:          com.acme.Foo@3251989283
Hexadecimal:      com.acme.Foo@C1D56B23
Tetrasexagesimal: com.acme.Foo@31rMiZ
```

Which one would you prefer?

I would definitely prefer the tetrasexagesimal, and in lack of that, I would settle for the hexadecimal one. Most people would agree.

One web site where you can play with conversions is here:
https://www.mobilefish.com/services/big_number/big_number.php

Comment: On a related note, if the numbers were displayed in decimal, people might be more prone to expect them to "mean" something.  For example, "Fnord #194" sounds a lot more like the 194th Fnord than "Fnord@159C8EA5".  From a mnemonic standpoint, other alphanumeric encodings might have been shorter and more easily distinguished, but I think Java wanted to avoid any possibility of producing any letter sequences which could be deemed offensive.

Comment: We use it for just this purpose.  I need to know (in storm) which Persist bolt of the 5 we have is persisting what amount.  So in our logging we use this to sort on a single instance of a bolt.