# Why Equals and Hashcode is same for list of objects even though I have not implemented those methods for that object

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, equals, hashcode

I have 3 classes

Employee class is like

```
  class Employee {
    int id;
    String name;
    long salary;
    List<Address> address;
    //getter setter, equals and hashcode and parameterized constructor}
```

And My address class is like

```
public class Address {
int housenum;
String streetname;
int pincode;
//getter setter and parameterized constructor
}
```

and My Test class is like

```
 Address address1 = new Address(10, "str 1", 400043);
            Address address2 = new Address(10, "str 1", 400043);

            List<Address> addressLst1= new ArrayList<>();
            List<Address> addressLst2= new ArrayList<>();
            addressLst1.add(address1);
            addressLst1.add(address2);
            addressLst2.add(address1);
            addressLst2.add(address2);
            Employee employee1 = new Employee(1, "EMP1", 1000, addressLst1);
            Employee employee2 = new Employee(1, "EMP1", 1000, addressLst2);

            Set<Employee> set = new HashSet<>();
            set.add(employee1);
            set.add(employee2);

            System.out.println(":::::::::::::::addressLst1:::::::::" + addressLst1.hashCode());
            System.out.println(":::::::::::::::addressLst2:::::::::" + addressLst2.hashCode());

            System.out.println(":::::::::::::::address1:::::::::" + address1.hashCode());
            System.out.println(":::::::::::::::address2:::::::::" + address2.hashCode());

            System.out.println(":::::::::::::::employee1:::::::::" + employee1.hashCode());
            System.out.println(":::::::::::::::employee2:::::::::" + employee2.hashCode());

            set.forEach(System.out::println);

            System.out.println(":::::::::::::::size:::::::::" + set.size());
```

I am getting different hashcode for address objects as I have not overridden equals and hashcode. But why I am getting same hashcode for two different lists of addresses i.e. addressLst1 and addressLst2  And why I am getting the size of set as 1, why the hashcode of two employee object is the same? And what is correct way to override equals and hashcode for the custom object which consist of list of another custom  object?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What issues should be considered when overriding equals and hashCode in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)

Comment: This already answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17159881/default-implementation-of-hashcode-returns-different-values-for-objects-construc

Comment: `{address1,address2}.equals({address1,address2})` since `address1.equals(address1)` and `address2.equals(address2)`; and `address1.equals(address1)` since `address1 == address1` (same for `address2`) - it uses `Object.equals()`, which just uses `==` itself, since `Address` has no `equals() `

Comment: `employee1.equals(employe2)` since its `equals` and `hashCode` are implemented to compare/use its attributes

Answer (score 2):

The two `List`s `addressLst1` and `addressLst2` contain the exact same elements in the exact same order, so the contract of `List`'s `equals` requires that these two `List`s will be equal to each other:

> **boolean java.util.List.equals(Object o)**
>
> Compares the specified object with this list for equality. Returns true if and only if the specified object is also a list, both lists have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two lists are equal. (Two elements e1 and e2 are equal if (e1==null ? e2==null :e1.equals(e2)).) In other words, two lists are defined to be equal if they contain the same elements in the same order. This definition ensures that the equals method works properly across different implementations of the List interface.

It doesn't matter that `Address` doesn't override `equals` and `hashCode`, since the `List`s contain references to the same objects. While `address1` is not equal to `address2`, both `List`s contain references to both `address1` and `address2` in the same order, so the `List`s are equal.

For the `Employee` class, you wrote that you did override `equals` and `hashCode`, so I'm assuming two `Employees` are equal if all of their properties are equal. Therefore the two `Employee` instances you try to add to the `Set` are equal.