# Difference between printing char and int arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays

When I run the following code I get the address of the array:

```
int arr[] = {2,5,3};
System.out.println(arr); // [I@3fe993
```

But when I declare a character array and print it the same way it gives me the actual content of the array. Why?

```
char ch[] = {'a','b','c'};
System.out.println(ch); // abc
```

Comment: They have different implementations of `.toString()`

Comment: Your link was right on the money. Sorry.

Comment: The answer seems to be: because `PrintStream` class has a method for `array of characters` and does not have for arrays of any other primitives.

Comment: And not to beat a dead horse for @BobDalgleish, but they _don't_ have different implementations. All arrays in Java have the same `toString`, which is just the `Object.toString`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Class `PrintStream` (which is what `System.out` is) has a dedicated method overload [`println(char[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-char:A-) which prints the characters of a char array.

It has no special overloads for other arrays, so when you pass an `int[]` the called method is [`println(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-java.lang.Object-). That method converts the passed object to a string by calling its `toString()` method.

The `toString()` method for all arrays is simply the default one inherited [from class `Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--), which displays their class name and default hashcode, which is why it's not so informative. You can use [`Arrays.toString(int[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-int:A-) to get a string representation of your int array's contents.

P.S. Contrary to what the doc says, the default hashcode of an object is not typically the object's address, but [a randomly generated number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105420/java-object-hashcode-address-or-random).

Comment: it is internally invoking `String.valueOf()`

Comment: @JigarJoshi Which on non-null objects such as this, calls `toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

When you say
System.out.println(ch);

It results in a call to print(char[] s) then println()

The [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println()) for println says:

Prints a character and then terminate the line. This method behaves as though it invokes print(char) and then println().

A integer variable is not char, so the print(int[] s) get the address of array.