# What is in Java object header?

Tags: java, jvm, java-memory-model, object-layout, jol

Could you give me some information on what is exactly stored in object header? I know, that it's probably JVM dependent, but maybe for HotSpot at least? I'm looking for exact description specifically for a first row.

I've read several information that I can't verify positively with information I find. Maybe you have a link to OpenJDK wiki that says it all?

Comment: There is a great video course available here that gives you lots of details on JVM presented in very accessible way: https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/optimizing-java/9781492044673/video323888.html

Answer (score 70, accepted):

**For HotSpot:**

**The object header consists of a mark word and a klass pointer.**

The **mark word** has word size (`4 byte` on 32 bit architectures, `8 byte` on 64 bit architectures) and

the **klass pointer** has word size on `32 bit` architectures. On `64 bit` architectures the klass pointer either has word size, but can also have `4 byte` if the heap addresses can be encoded in these `4 bytes`.

This optimization is called **"compressed oops"** and you can also control it with the option `UseCompressedOops`.

You can also find a wiki entry about this [1](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/87ee5ee27509/src/share/vm/oops/markOop.hpp).

The **mark word** is actually used for many things.

1. One is `Biased Locking` [2](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/87ee5ee27509/src/share/vm/oops/oop.hpp) through which HotSpot can implement efficient locking.
2. It is also used during `GC to set forward pointers`, and `to store the age of the objects`. The identity hash code of an object can be stored inside the mark (the `System.identityHashCode`/`Object.hashCode` one).

There is a comment in the source code of [markOop.hpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/87ee5ee27509/src/share/vm/oops/markOop.hpp) that describes the layout depending on the architecture:

```
//  32 bits:
//  --------
//             hash:25 ------------>| age:4    biased_lock:1 lock:2 (normal object)
//             JavaThread*:23 epoch:2 age:4    biased_lock:1 lock:2 (biased object)
//             size:32 ------------------------------------------>| (CMS free block)
//             PromotedObject*:29 ---------->| promo_bits:3 ----->| (CMS promoted object)
//
//  64 bits:
//  --------
//  unused:25 hash:31 -->| unused:1   age:4    biased_lock:1 lock:2 (normal object)
//  JavaThread*:54 epoch:2 unused:1   age:4    biased_lock:1 lock:2 (biased object)
//  PromotedObject*:61 --------------------->| promo_bits:3 ----->| (CMS promoted object)
//  size:64 ----------------------------------------------------->| (CMS free block)
//
//  unused:25 hash:31 -->| cms_free:1 age:4    biased_lock:1 lock:2 (COOPs && normal object)
//  JavaThread*:54 epoch:2 cms_free:1 age:4    biased_lock:1 lock:2 (COOPs && biased object)
//  narrowOop:32 unused:24 cms_free:1 unused:4 promo_bits:3 ----->| (COOPs && CMS promoted object)
//  unused:21 size:35 -->| cms_free:1 unused:7 ------------------>| (COOPs && CMS free block)
```

You can also find the oop header file [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/87ee5ee27509/src/share/vm/oops/oop.hpp).

- [1](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/87ee5ee27509/src/share/vm/oops/markOop.hpp) https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/CompressedOops
- [2](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/87ee5ee27509/src/share/vm/oops/oop.hpp) https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/Synchronization

Answer (score 4):

You can find the object layout from [HotSpot sources](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/tip/src/share/vm/oops/oop.hpp#l59).

The header consists of [markOop](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/tip/src/share/vm/oops/markOop.hpp#l30) followed by a pointer (or compressed pointer) to [instanceKlass](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/tip/src/share/vm/oops/instanceKlass.hpp#l43).

Answer (score 4):

The following presentation gives you a general idea of the object contents and the object header:
http://www.slideshare.net/cnbailey/memory-efficient-java

The actual header for any object is JVM vendor, version and object type specific.

Comment: This overall feeling many readers probably have is they'd better use a language that doesn't impose GC.