# Is the 4 bytes of an array of type int distributed among the elements of the array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, memory, ram

I want to know if the datatype of an array is the datatype of each element or the whole array. For instance, will this code reserve 4 bytes or 16 bytes of RAM?

```
int[] collection = {30, 40, 50, 60};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of the 4 int values use 4 bytes.

However the array uses a object header which is 8 - 12 bytes long in the OpenJDK (and like JVMS)

The object alignment is 8 bytes by default so the size of the object will be rounded up to a multiple of 8.

This means the object could be 24 to 32 bytes long.

The reference to this object will be 4 bytes unless you have a 64-bit JVM which has Compressed Oops disabled.

[What is in java object header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357186/what-is-in-java-object-header)

[Document -XX:ObjectAlignmentInBytes](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8040176)

[Compressed OOPs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html#compressedOop)

Comment: I added a link to a presentation

Answer (score 1):

This is an array of four elements, where each one is an `int`. Since a single `int` takes 4 bytes, the array will take a total of 4*4 = 16 bytes.

Comment: Also, 32 or 64 bits for the array reference??