# How much memory is taken by an int[n][]?

Tags: java, memory

For example, declaring a `new int[n][n]` in java will result in n array references with each array containing n elements.

If I declare a `new int[n][]`, how much memory will this take? I suspect it is just n references to null, but I want to confirm this.

Comment: Why don't you write a simple program to test this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java we have the following sizes:

`int` = 4 bytes

`int[]` = 4N + 24 bytes

`int[][]` ~4MN bytes

`Array` = 24 bytes + memory for each array entry

So, your array `new int[n][]` is one-dimensional array from `0` to `n`. It takes a `4N+24` bytes (`24` bytes for array + `4*N` bytes for each array entry) typically.

By the way, it is JVM dependent and may be a more accurate answer is `~4N` bytes plus a header information.

Comment: Do you have any reference for your " + 24 bytes"? If you have, it's possibly outdated. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357186/what-is-in-java-object-header or related posts.

Comment: @Erwin Bolwidt , probably it is JVM dependent. I take this number from algs4.cs.princeton.edu/14analysis.