# Why does Oracle display RAW column value in HEX?

Tags: oracle

Using Spring Boot/Hibernate/Jpa
i have a model in which i defined:

```
@Column(name="greenRange", nullable = true)
private int[] greenRange;


public int[] getGreenRange() {
    return greenRange;
}

public void setGreenRange(int[] greenRange) {
    this.greenRange = greenRange;
}
```

and a simple test method that sets the range to a 2 element array containing ints 2 and 8.

Now, once the values have been persisted, the value of the column is

> ACED0005757200025B494DBA602676EAB2A50200007870000000020000000100000008

What could this be?

EDIT: The datatype of the column is RAW.
EDIT2: Using Oracle SQL Developer. I am able to print the value after accessing the entity again.

```
Array.length    array[0]  array[1]
[000000002][00000001][00000008]

?
[ACED0005757200025B494DBA602676EAB2A5020000787]
```

Comment: What is the definition of the column in the database? Without knowing that we cannot help you.

Comment: I suspect that it is a hex representation of the `int[]` object. Just for fun, try storing the array `{3,5}' or something else. Compare the results.

Comment: what could what be? Is that what the DB says its value is? if so what DB tool says this?, what your debug says it is?, if so printed out using some method?

Comment: DBMS - Oracle Express Studio, The debug prints the values fine, not sure what you mean by what debug says, inspecting the array gives the normal representation with @<id> and two values.

Comment: looks like 70 32bit integers to me.

Comment: How much memory do you have that it could be a memory location?!

Comment: @bradimus ACED0005757200025B494DBA602676EAB2A50200007870000000020000000300000005 with"greenRange": [3, 5]

Comment: `[000000002]` is probably the length of the array.

Comment: `[ACED0005757200025B494DBA602676EAB2A5020000787]` is probably the [java `Object` header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357186/what-is-in-java-object-header)

Answer (score -1):

I think that might be the hex representation of the int[] object.
Please check oracle docs:
[Overview of RAW and LONG RAW Datatypes](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i4146)

> When Oracle Database automatically converts RAW or LONG RAW data to and from CHAR data, the binary data is represented in hexadecimal form with one hexadecimal character representing every four bits of RAW data. For example, one byte of RAW data with bits 11001011 is displayed and entered as 'CB'.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Well, indeed, it is true. I will take it into account. Thanks for advice:)