# Boxing vs creating array of 1 element

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jmh

Disclaimer: I read [***this article***](https://shipilev.net/talks/devoxx-Nov2013-benchmarking.pdf) by Alexey Shipilev and understood that nanobenchmarks a kind of evil. But anyway want to experiment and understand by myself.

I'm trying to measure array creation vs boxing of `byte`. Here is my benchmark:

```
@Fork(1)
@Warmup(iterations = 5, timeUnit = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
@Measurement(iterations = 5, timeUnit = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
public class MyBenchmark {

    @Benchmark
    @OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
    public void arrayBenchmark(Blackhole bh) {
        byte[] b = new byte[1];
        b[0] = 20;
        bh.consume(b);
    }

    @Benchmark
    @OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
    public void bonxingBenchmark(Blackhole bh) {
        bh.consume(new Byte((byte) 20));
    }
}
```

I ran this benchmark several times and for some reason I figured out that boxing is 1.5 times faster than creation of array and putting element into it

So I decided to run this benchmarks with `-prof gc`. The result is this:

```
MyBenchmark.arrayBenchmark                                     avgt    5     7.751 ±    0.537   ns/op
MyBenchmark.arrayBenchmark:·gc.alloc.rate                      avgt    5  1966.743 ±  143.624  MB/sec
MyBenchmark.arrayBenchmark:·gc.alloc.rate.norm                 avgt    5    24.000 ±    0.001    B/op
MyBenchmark.arrayBenchmark:·gc.churn.PS_Eden_Space             avgt    5  1966.231 ±  326.378  MB/sec
MyBenchmark.arrayBenchmark:·gc.churn.PS_Eden_Space.norm        avgt    5    23.999 ±    4.148    B/op
MyBenchmark.arrayBenchmark:·gc.churn.PS_Survivor_Space         avgt    5     0.042 ±    0.113  MB/sec
MyBenchmark.arrayBenchmark:·gc.churn.PS_Survivor_Space.norm    avgt    5     0.001 ±    0.001    B/op
MyBenchmark.arrayBenchmark:·gc.count                           avgt    5    37.000             counts
MyBenchmark.arrayBenchmark:·gc.time                            avgt    5    48.000                 ms

MyBenchmark.bonxingBenchmark                                   avgt    5     6.123 ±    1.306   ns/op
MyBenchmark.bonxingBenchmark:·gc.alloc.rate                    avgt    5  1664.504 ±  370.508  MB/sec
MyBenchmark.bonxingBenchmark:·gc.alloc.rate.norm               avgt    5    16.000 ±    0.001    B/op
MyBenchmark.bonxingBenchmark:·gc.churn.PS_Eden_Space           avgt    5  1644.547 ± 1004.476  MB/sec
MyBenchmark.bonxingBenchmark:·gc.churn.PS_Eden_Space.norm      avgt    5    15.769 ±    7.495    B/op
MyBenchmark.bonxingBenchmark:·gc.churn.PS_Survivor_Space       avgt    5     0.037 ±    0.067  MB/sec
MyBenchmark.bonxingBenchmark:·gc.churn.PS_Survivor_Space.norm  avgt    5    ≈ 10⁻³               B/op
MyBenchmark.bonxingBenchmark:·gc.count                         avgt    5    23.000             counts
MyBenchmark.bonxingBenchmark:·gc.time                          avgt    5    37.000                 ms
```

As we can see, the `GC` is heavily loaded in `arrayBenchmark` case. Allocation rate `1966` vs `1664`. `gc-count` and `gc-time` also differs. ***I think that's the cause***, but not sure

For now I don't quite understand that behaviour. I thought array allocation in my case just means that we allocate 1 byte somewhere. To me it looks pretty much the same as `Boxing`, but actually different.

Can you help me to understand it?

And what's most important... Can I trust this benchmark?

Comment: offtopic: but your 6666 reputation looks more than evil to me too... not even talking about the avatar pic....

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ Offtopic: give my +1 so my reputation is OK again :)

Comment: So, I could be wrong about this, but I believe what you might be seeing is the extraneous information that is stored due to the fact that it is an array, things like `.length` property

Comment: Done!! LOL ... now we hoppe you dont get 5 downvotes :)

Comment: @CraigR8806 Actually, maybe.... But how can I make sure about it? Maybe there is some profiler for that?

Comment: You would have to have a runtime profiler that can inspect the local variable table and even then, I'm not sure that it would show you exactly what is being allocated.

Comment: @CraigR8806 The question is can I even trust this benchmark?

Comment: I've seen you ask a lot of very low level, nitty-gritty detail questions about Java. Can I ask what you're doing with all this? Is it just academic curiosity, or are you planning on something special? Comparing `Byte` with `byte[1]` is a bit like comparing apples with an array of oranges after all.

Comment: @Kayaman Just interesting to investigate. But have some troubles to understand what's going on under the hood.

Comment: With the array version you *may* incur the overhead of bounds checking when assigning the value to the array. You could try replacing it with `byte[] b = new byte[] { 20 };` and see what that does (if anything, it might be JITted away) to the benchmark.

Comment: @St.Antario what do you mean by "Can I trust this benchmark"? It is not clear what is the difference between your expectations and the data you have got from the benchmark, so it is not really clear what kind of answer you expect.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin I'm investigating the GC activity difference

Comment: You allocate different objects, that explains the difference, doesn't it?

Comment: @OlegEstekhin I thought arrays in java internally represented a contingious properly aligned memory, so it should have been more efficient to use arrays... but I was wrong.

Comment: actually, gc.alloc.rate.norm clearly shows, that array benchmark allocates 24 bytes per run, while wrapper allocates 16

Comment: arrays are contingious and properly aligned, but how it leads to "more efficient" conclusion?

Comment: @OlegEstekhin it does not... I just want to understand the difference in gc activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR it's because of Java objects [memory layout](http://psy-lob-saw.blogspot.ru/2013/05/know-thy-java-object-memory-layout.html)* and array overhead.

Every object has [header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357186/what-is-in-java-object-header) (where identity hashcode, locks and gc meta-information is stored) and class pointer. Additionally, address of object should be aligned to 8.

Assuming you are on x86-64 processor, header size is 8 byte and class pointer size is 4 bytes.
`byte` field in `Byte` takes 1 byte => `Byte` should take 13 bytes, but rounding to alignment gives you exactly 16 bytes, which you observed with `-prof gc`.

For array calculations are mostly the same, but array has 4 byte `length` field (technically speaking, it's not a real field, but it doesn't really matter), which gives you `8 + 4 + 4 = 16` bytes for array and 1 byte for single byte element, which with alignment gives you 24 bytes.

So one of the reasons is that array is just larger object.

Second reason is more complex code for array creation (you can look at generated code with `-prof perfasm` or `-prof dtraceasm`). Array initialization requires additional store into `length` field, also (I don't know why) JIT generates four `prefetchnta` instructions.

So yes, you can partially trust it: allocating single element is **slightly** (though not x1.5 times) slower.

*Note that all this is relevant only to Hotspot and other JVMs may have different layout.

Comment: Actually I have a question. You said that class pointers also stored in the headers, but... if we take a look at [markOop](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/ff3b27e6bcc2/src/share/vm/oops/markOop.hpp#l44) we will find the header desription for 64bVM. No class pointer specified there.

Comment: Have never used `-dtraceasm`.  Can you add a bit description about it?

Comment: @St.Antario I said the opposite: "Every object has header **and** class pointer." `dtraceasm` is analogue of `perfasm`, but works on Mac OS X. Added in JMH 1.20

Comment: Thanks, understood. Just looked at assembly generated by `arrayBenchmark` method. Also noticed (3, not four like in your case) `prefetchnta`. Also I did not notice any `aastore` instruction (for `b[0] = 20`)... It was JITed from the jmh loop?

Comment: @St.Antario JIT behaviour may vary. Store should be present as `movq   $0x14, 0x10(%rax)` right after allocation (there may be other register though, but constants should be the same). `$0x14` is hex constant for 20

Comment: My bad, was looking for `12` instead of `14`... Now I see, thanks. Anyway, this is the code related to the JMH stub method. Seems the method was inlined there... Ran it with `CompilerControl.Mode.DONT_INLINE`, seems the `prefetchnta`  we saw before were the jmh staff...?

Comment: @St.Antario it's related to `arrayBenchmark`, just inlined into JMH-stub. You can experiment with `@CompilerControl` or compilation log to validate it

Comment: @St.Antario `prefetchnta` is related to allocation code (to `new`, to prefetch area behind allocation to simplify next allocation), not to JMH infra. It will not be gone unless you explicitly disabled it with `-XX:AllocatePrefetchStyle=0`

Comment: I have one more question... Is it possible to attach with gdb to jmh benchmark when running? I mean `-perfasm` printed some code, I would like to debug it during benchmark execution. The issue is it's printed after benchmarking is finished. I can attach with gdb to a regular java process and debug it, that's pretty straightforward.... Can you advice something? Is it at all possible?

Comment: @St.Antario it's definitely possible, though I never tried to do it with running JMH benchmark. You need fast/slow-debug build of openjdk (you can find one here: https://builds.shipilev.net/). Next step is to watch one of Volker Simonis talks (e.g. google "volker simonis gdb")  and then just run `gdb java ...` :)

Comment: the problem is when attaching to JMH fork the benchmark are running in the instruction addresses given by `-XX:PrintAssembly` seems to change over time so gdb just signals `cannot set break by the address`. With simple java app I added `Thread.sleep` after a method was compiled and debug it. It seems that debugging jmh benchamrks... If possible, but not as easy.

Comment: As I said, I've never tried this, so can't really help. But if generated code is changed then you are trying to attach to benchmark when it's not in steady state. Before steady state code is usually recompiled multiple times