# int arrays to json object in java

Tags: java, arrays, json

I'm trying to put two int [] and a double [] in JSON format to send through my java servlet. This is what I have so far.

```
private JSONObject doStuff(double[] val, int[] col_idx, int[] row_ptr){
    String a = JSONValue.toJSONString(val);
    String b = JSONValue.toJSONString(col_idx);
    String c = JSONValue.toJSONString(row_ptr);
    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
    jo.put("val",a)
    jo.put("col",b);
    jo.put("row",c);
    return jo;
}
```

But when I print the JSONobject, I get this unreadable result:

```
{"val":"[D@62ce3190","col":"[I@4f18179d","row":"[I@36b66cfc"}
```

I get the same result in javascript where I am sending the JSONObject to.
Is there a problem with the conversion from numbers to string? Should I perhaps use JSONArray instead?

Comment: If you try printing `val` on the console, it will print the same thing. It is the address of `val` array and similarly for the others.

Comment: Indeed. `String a = Arrays.toString(val)` did the trick though.

Comment: You need to first convert your arrays into readable format(convert it into list using Arrays.asList()), and then process it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is because the `toString` method of `int[]` or `double[]` is returning the Object's default `Object.toString()`.

Replace with `Arrays.toString(int[]/double[])`, you will get expected result.

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33057841/1699979) for more explantion about toString.

Comment: I figured it out riiight before your answer, but thanks. Will mark this as the correct answer after the "you can accept an answer in 3 minutes" prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
jo.put("val",a)
jo.put("col",b);
jo.put("row",c);
```

Use;

```
jo.put("val",val);
jo.put("col",col_idx);
jo.put("row",row_ptr);
```